# Let's integrate Ask Ubuntu badges with the operating system!

Tags: discussion, badges, ubuntu-community

Jono and Marco have been working on integrating the Ask Ubuntu badges you earn here with the [Ubuntu Accomplishment system](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments).

This is basically badges, but at a higher project level, so of course we want people's Ask Ubuntu work to count as trophies in Ubuntu as a whole.

In order to do this we need to basically create a small text file for each badge so that the Ubuntu accomplishment system knows what to do. Ends up there are a ton more badges than you'd think, so we'd like to see if people can chip in helping us get this done:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Accomplishments/Creating/Guide/AccomplishmentFile

Answer (score 19):

Please remember that an important goal of these accomplishments is that the documentation should be detailed: think of it as a wikipedia for how to get started with a particular Ask Ubuntu badge.

To write an accomplishment file do this:

```
bzr branch lp:ubuntu-community-accomplishments
cd ubuntu-community-accomplishments/accomplishments/ubuntu-community/en/support
```

In there you should see a bunch of .accomplishment files, each corresponding to a badge. Open it up, it should look like this:

```
[accomplishment]
title=Altruist on Ask Ubuntu
description=First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
collection=ubuntu-community
category=Ask Ubuntu:Bounty
icon=askubuntu-gold.png
needs-signing=true
needs-information=askubuntu-user-url
summary = Explain here in detail what this badge is, and what is involved is accomplishing it.
steps: Provide step by step instructions for to accomplish this.
    Each step should be on a new line with a tab at the beginning, like this.
links: http://www.askubuntu.com
tips: Things and recommendations that people might find useful in earning the accomplishment.
pitfalls: Provide tips to avoid
    So users can learn
help = #ubuntu-community-team on Freenode
author = Jorge Castro <jorge@ubuntu.com>
```

You only need to fix up icon, steps, tips, pitfalls, and author, you can leave the rest alone.

- **category** - The format is `category=Ask Ubuntu:subcategory`. For the list of subcategories, use this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68259/150182).
- **icon** - for the icons, use use the same icon as used by Ask Ubuntu (e.g. if it is Gold on Ask Ubuntu, ensure it has the gold icon in Ubuntu Accomplishments. You can use the following filenames: `askubuntu-gold.png`, `askubuntu-silver.png`, and `askubuntu-bronze.png` for the icons corresponding to each badge.
- **summary** - this should be a detailed description of the badge and what is involved. For example if you are talking about your profile, explain what a profile is, why the user should care, and how they access it. To start a new paragraph, start a new line and put a tab at the beginning.
- **steps** - add a series of chrononological steps for how to accomplish the badge. To add a new step, start a new line and put a tab at the beginning.
- **tips** - add a series of tips that can help someone be successful in accomplishing the badge. To add a new tip, start a new line and put a tab at the beginning.
- **pitfalls** - add a series of things the user should *not* do. To add a new pitfall, start a new line and put a tab at the beginning.

Save your file, and then submit it by doing:

```
bzr commit
```

And then add a changelog entry, something like "Added the yearling badge", then save and push:

```
bzr push lp:~yourlaunchpadusername/ubuntu-community-accomplishments/give-your-branch-a-cool-name-here
```

Now open your branch in your browser:

```
bzr lp-open
```

And then click on "Propose for merging" and then add a decription, paste in `lp:ubuntu-community-accomplishments` for the branch you want to propose into and click "Submit".

Tips:

- You can remove the tag description that says "This badge can be earned multiple times" as the Ubuntu system only awards for the first time.
- All the descriptions are on the [badge page](https://askubuntu.com/badges) so you can copy and paste those.

Once you've submitted the accomplishment file cross it off this list.

- <s>Altruist</s> - Marco
- <s>Analytical</s> - Marco
- <s>Announcer</s> - Marco
- <s>Archaeologist</s> - Marco
- <s>Autobiographer</s> - Marco
- <s>Benefactor</s> - Marco
- <s>Beta</s> - Marco
- <s>Booster</s> - Marco
- <s>Citizen Patrol</s> - Marco
- <s>Civic Duty</s> - Marco
- <s>Cleanup</s> - Marco
- <s>Commentator</s> - Marco
- <s>Convention</s> - Marco
- <s>Copy Editor</s> - Marco
- <s>Critic</s> - Agmenor
- <s>Deputy</s> - Marco
- <s>Disciplined</s> - Marco
- Editor - Marco
- Electorate - Marco
- Enlightened - Marco
- Enthusiast - Marco
- Epic - Marco
- Excavator - Marco
- <s>Famous Question</s> - htorque
- <s>Fanatic</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Favorite Question</s> - htorque
- **Generalist**
- <s>Good Answer</s> - George Edison
- <s>Good Question</s> - htorque
- <s>Great Answer</s> - jorge
- <s>Great Question</s> - jorge
- **Guru**
- **Investor**
- **Legendary**
- **Marshal**
- **Mortarboard**
- **Necromancer**
- <s>Nice Answer</s> - htorque
- <s>Nice Question</s>  - htorque
- <s>Notable Question</s> - htorque
- <s>Organizer</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Outspoken</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Peer Pressure</s> - htorque
- <s>Popular Question</s> - htorque
- <s>Populist</s> - htorque
- <s>Precognitive</s> - htorque
- <s>Promoter</s> - htorque
- <s>Proofreader</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Publicist</s> - htorque
- <s>Pundit</s> - htorque
- <s>Quorum</s> - htorque
- **Research Assistant**
- **Reversal**
- **Reviewer**
- **Revival**
- <s>Scholar</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Self-Learner</s> - surgemcgee
- <s>Sportsmanship</s> - surgemcgee
- <s>Stellar Question</s> - surgemcgee
- <s>Strunk & White</s> - surgemcgee
- <s>Student</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Suffrage</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Supporter</s> - WarriorIng64
- **Synonymizer**
- <s>Tag Editor</s> - jorge
- <s>Talkative</s> - WarriorIng64
- <s>Taxonomist</s> - jorge
- <s>Teacher</s> - WarriorIng64
- <strike>Tenacious</strike> - jorge
- <strike>Tumbleweed</strike> - jorge
- <strike>Unsung Hero</strike> - jorge
- <strike>Vox Populi</strike> - jorge
- <strike>Yearling</strike> - jorge

Comment: Pretty neat. Will help out.

Comment: You want it to match the badge, askubuntu-gold.png, askubuntu-silver.png, and askubuntu-bronze.png

Comment: I think I did it wrong, the only thing inside the askubuntu-accomplishments is .bzr. There is no other directory there.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Also, I put a tips: field before pitfalls. It is not in the example.

Comment: Will also have a look at it later today. Jono just received the "Motivate Hernando Badge". :P

Comment: htorque - thanks for your awesome contributions! I look forward to seeing more. :-)

Comment: Awesome community → awesome contributions. ;-)

Comment: Just thought I'd note that it seems Launchpad already has `lp:ubuntu-community-accomplishments` selected as the branch to merge into by default when you propose the merge.